How to pass in a long text from a document to a RAG for validating text?
I am programming an application that has a manual with criterias for a certain type of document as its knowledge in a RAG.
I then want to pass in the text from a document, and let the LLM based on the context of the manual decide if the text is a valid document.
How would I approach this? Everything I find when researching is RAGs where all you can do is pass in a question related to the context.
